# How do I switch from using require statements to imports with typescript in my mocha tests?

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, module, mocha.js

I have the following values in package.json:

```
     "scripts": {
            "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register security.test.ts"
        },
         "type": "module", 
          .
          .
          .
         "devDependencies": {
            "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
            "esm": "^3.2.25",
            "mocha": "^10.2.0",
            "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
            "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
            "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
```

My tsconfig.json file:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ESNext",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node"
      },
      "ts-node": {
        "esm": true,
        "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
      },
      "include": [
            "*.ts",
            "**/*.ts",
            "**/*.test.ts"
    ]
  }
```

Inside of my security.test.ts file, I have

```
import { describe, it, before, after } from "mocha";

  describe("Testing for project", async () => {
 
      before(async () => {
        console.log("before");
      });
    
      after(async () => {
        console.log("ran after");
      });
```

I am just getting this error with every configuration I try, unless I switch it back to require statements:

> mocha -r ts-node/register security.test.ts

```
 TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /myfilepath.ts
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:121:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:81:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26)
    at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34)
```

What am I missing?  Is it supposed to be such a pain to make that switch?

Answer (score 0):

**tsconfig file**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "include": [
    "*.ts",
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require ts-node/register security.test.ts",
    "start": "node -r ts-node/register your-script.ts"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

**Ensure that you have the necessary dependencies installed by running**
`npm install ts-node mocha @types/mocha --save-dev`

**security.test.ts**

```
describe("Testing for project", async () => {
  before(async () => {
    console.log("before");
  });

  after(async () => {
    console.log("ran after");
  });

  it("should run a test", async () => {
    // Add your test logic here
  });
});
```

after changes this file then start npm test

Comment: With the command  "mocha -r ts-node/register security.test.ts" I still get the same error.

Comment: Verify that you have installed the necessary dependencies for running tests with Mocha and TypeScript
`npm install --save-dev mocha ts-node`

Comment: I edited the package.json above to show all my dev dependencies.  I had both installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found the right configuration in this example:

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha-examples/tree/master/packages/typescript

Key points:
1.) You can keep the module as "commonjs"
2.) A .mocharc.json file with "require":"ts-node/register" and "spec": "FILEPATH/*.test.ts",
3.) Simple "mocha" command

I think the spec entry in .mocharc.json file was the only piece I hadn't tried.